# Grails: Can't figure out why I'm getting a 404

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 1.3.6.  I have this file ...

grails-app/views/home/design/index.gsp

Here is what is defined in my HomeController.  Sadly, whenever I visit, "http://localhost:port/context-path/design/", I get a 404 error.  The server starts normally and there are no errors in the logs.  What can I do to get my page instead of the 404?

```
def index = {
    def folder = params.folder;
    def page = params.page;

    if (page) { 
        try { 
            def contents = IOService.getFileContents(folder, page)  
            response.setContentType("application/json")
            response << contents
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            response.status = 404;
        }   // try
    } else { 
        render(view: "/home/${folder}/index") 
    }   // if
}
```

My URLMappings file consists of ...

```
static mappings = {
    "/$folder?/$page"{
        controller = "home"
        action = "index"
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Did you mean to visit `/context-path/home/design`? (that would still 404 with your current classes, but would make your example line up a bit better)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to access

```
/context-path/home/design
```

Your action needs to be named design, i.e.

```
class HomeController {
    def design = {

    }
}
```

The Grails convention is always `/context-path/controllerName/actionName` (unless you have it mapped differently in `grails-app/conf/URLMappings.groovy`).

Your example's a bit unclear which path you're trying to access. To address both:

- If you want `/context-path/design`, you need a `DesignController` with an `index` action (because if no action is supplied in the URL, Grails looks for the `index` action).
- If you want `/context-path/home/design`, you need a `HomeController` with a `design` action.

**Edit**:

In the comments, you express the want to be able to have `/context-path/design` map to the HomeController index action. You can do this with `grails-app/conf/URLMappings.groovy`:

```
"/design"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want the URL to be "/context-path/home/design", I want it to be "/context-path/design".  I realize what I'm asking might be unconventional, but if its possible to do it from the "HomeController", that is what we want to do.  Thanks, -

Comment: Hi Dave, have a look at the documentation for UrlMappings: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4 URL Mappings

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I'm trying to do.  If they enter the URL "folder/page", I want to serve up static JSON content.  Otherwise if they just enter "folder/", I want to serve the view located in grails-app/views/home/folder/index.gsp.  Any suggestions to further this effort?

Comment: Do you know if the request actually hits the action? Since you respond with a 404 in the action, the 404 could either be the controller/action not being found, or the folder not being found. Perhaps add a log to verify that?

Comment: Hi Rob, Per your edit, I DON'T want "/context-path/design/" to hit the HomeController index action, I want it to render the view at "views/home/design/index.gsp".  Same for "/context-path/photos/" to hit "views/home/photos/index.gsp".  Ditto for the other 25 directories under home.  Logs didn't answer your other comment, sadly but I appreciate your help and hope my clarification makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you have two distinct actions, I would set things up a bit differently:

```
def indexWithPage = {
    def folder = params.folder;
    def page = params.page;

    try { 
        def contents = IOService.getFileContents(folder, page)  
        response.setContentType("application/json")
        response << contents
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        response.status = 404;
    }   // try
}

def index
    def folder = params.folder;

    render(view: "/home/${folder}/index") 
}
```

with a URLMaping of:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$folder/$page"{
        controller = "home"
        action = "indexWithPage"
    }

    "/$folder"{
        controller = "home"
        action = "index"
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

I also threw a e.printStackTrace(); in there to help us determine whether you're getting YOUR 404 or the action is truely not being called.